# I want to use onclick event after a template rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

Here is controller

```
    def findQuestionForSet(){
    def question = Questions.findAllBySetName(params.setName)
        println params.setName
        println question
        render(template: 'viewquestion', model: [questions : question])         

}
```

here is view code

```
<div id="viewquestion" class="show">
    <fieldset class="form">
        <g:render template="viewquestion" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Here is template _viewquestion

```
 <g:each in="${questions}" var="question">
<g:formRemote name="editfrom" url="[controller: 'questions', action: 'editquestion']">
    <g:textField id ="text${question.id}" class="text" name="question" required="" disabled value="${question.question}"/>
    <g:textField id ="textset" name="setName" required="" disabled value="${question.setName}"/>
    <input type="button" class="edit" id="edit${question.id}" value="edit">
    <g:submitButton name="save"/>
</g:formRemote>
</g:each>
```

Here is jquery code

```
    $(".edit").on("click", function(){

        var realid;
        realid = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(realid);

    });
```

May be here is some collision between server side and client site can any one help me to sort out the problem also how to solve this.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function() {}
```

hope it will solve your problem and if you want to call it after load you can use
`$(window).load(function(){})`
but I think above solution will work for you